Manually set Header height in Frozen Columns Datable(Bokeh python)
Is there a way to independently set manual Header height in Frozen Columns Datable(Bokeh python) and maintain the horizontall scrollbar for frozen columns at the same time?
Adding <'br'> to header text does move the succedding text to the next line, but the header height does not change even when the table is set to height_policy = 'auto',however the horzontal scrollbar does vanish*.
Header height not modified as per "br-NEWLINE BREAK"
autosize_mode = 'none' & width = 70(not auto but hardcoded) is mandatory to accomodate space constraints in larger tables.
Also,is bokeh_datatable just Jquery table as there is a console log to install Jquery for certain features to activate features?
CODE:
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, DataTable, TableColumn,Div
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.io import show

data = {
    "Product" : ['A','B','C','D','E',],
    "Future Index Long" : [1,2,3,4,5],
    "Future Index Short" : [1,2,3,4,5],
    "Future Index Positive" : [1,2,3,4,5],
    "Future Index Negative" : [1,2,3,4,5],
    "Future Index Up" : [1,2,3,4,5],
    "Future Index Down" : [1,2,3,4,5],
}

src = ColumnDataSource(data)


# width = 70(not auto) is mandatory to accomodate space constraints in larger tables
table_columns = [
    TableColumn(field="Product",title="Product",width=70,),
    TableColumn(field="Future Index Long",title="Future Index<br>Long",width=70,),
    TableColumn(field="Future Index Short",title="Future Index<br>Short",width=70,),
    TableColumn(field="Future Index Positive",title="Future Index<br>Positive",width=70,),
    TableColumn(field="Future Index Negative",title="Future Index<br>Negative",width=70,),
    TableColumn(field="Future Index Up",title="Future Index<br>Up",width=70,),
    TableColumn(field="Future Index Down",title="Future Index<br>Down",width=70,),

]


# Header height not modified as per <br>
data_table = DataTable(source=src, columns= table_columns, width=400, height=200, frozen_columns=1,header_row = True,height_policy = 'auto')
# data_table = DataTable(source=src, columns= table_columns, width=400, height=200, frozen_columns=1,header_row = True,height_policy = 'auto',autosize_mode = 'none')
title = Div(text=f"""<b>Manually set Header height.</b><br> Header height not modified as per "br-NEWLINE BREAK"<br>autosize_mode = 'none' & width = 70(not auto but hardcoded) is mandatory to accomodate space constraints in larger tables.<br><br>Also,is bokeh_datatable just Jquery table?</br>""", width_policy = 'auto', height=70,margin = 25)
layout = column(title,data_table)
show(layout)

